# ValueErrorThe truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas

Anyone aware of this error. I am facing this issue in this function. It is not going to IF statement where I put my filter condition which is true then simply raise Error and without IF it is working but I want to put the filter condition which checks date between some date and current date if condition true then fail the schedule

```
res = []
dates = pd.to_datetime(df['data_date'])
filt = (dates <= '2000-01-01') | (dates >= current_Date)
for col in INDEX_COLS:
    for i,d in enumerate(dates.values):
        if dates.loc[filt]:
            raise ValueError ("Date {} are not correct".format(k))
        else:
            res.append([d.split(" ")[0], col, df.loc[i,col]])
return pd.DataFrame(res, columns=["data_date", "index_code", "value"])
```

the error I am getting is:

> ValueErrorThe truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Comment: A lot of details are missing. Can you explain what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
I found the answer I was using incorrect format as the input string was different to which I am converting.

   res = []
    # dates = pd.to_datetime(df['data_date'])
    dates = df['data_date']
    prev_date = '01/01/2000'
    prev_cmp = datetime.strptime(prev_date, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
    cur_date = datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    cur_cmp = datetime.strptime(cur_date, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
    # filt = ((dates <= '2000-01-01') | (dates >= current_Date))
    for col in INDEX_COLS:
        # date values are in same order that rows in the dataframe - enumeration provides correct row indexes
        for i,d in enumerate(dates.values) :
            try:
                error_list = []
                d_temp = datetime.strptime(d, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
            except Exception as e:
                print("kalu")
            if ((d_temp < prev_cmp) or (d_temp > cur_cmp)):
                error_list.append(d)
            else:
                res.append([d.split(" ")[0], col, df.loc[i,col]])
            if error_list:
                raise ValueError("Dates {} are not correct".format(error_list))
    return pd.DataFrame(res, columns=["data_date", "index_code", "value"])

print(_transform_to_long_format(df))
```